# Can we ask questions about photographic scouting and photojournalistic technique?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

Are questions about photojournalistic technique on topic?

For example, here is an [article about tips for photographing golf tournaments](https://www.picturecorrect.com/tips/golf-photography-tips/). Are questions along the lines in the article on topic? What about questions that involve how to move around and lie in wait; that aren't really about cameras or photography per se, but more about how to sneak up on a subject and catch them at the right time?

Along the same lines are we allowed to ask questions about other photojournalism issues, like whether flash is allowed to be used at golf tournaments, or what rules a particular tournament like the Masters might impose on photojournalists?

Answer (score 3):

We have a number of 'how do I set up to get the shot I want' type of questions. This can range from how to hold a camera to how to gain access to a subject not generally available to just anyone.

In my personal opinion, I think the (fuzzy) line should be somewhere around questions that involve things directly related to putting one's self in the right spot at the right time to get a photo one desires to take.

As far as specific rules for a specific event (such as can one use flash at a golf tournament or what restrictions must photojournalists agree to in order to obtain media credentials), that's probably a little off subject here since those types of things are subject to change at the whim of the hosts and sanctioning bodies of such events.

It's probably OK to ask, "Is flash photography allowed at gymnastics meets?" because the overwhelming majority of such events prohibit it and very likely will continue to prohibit it for the foreseeable future.

It's probably not OK to ask, "Does the XYZ school district prohibit flash photography at high school football games?" because there is no broad universal answer to that question and any organization may choose to change their rules and how strictly they enforce it.